# DDL trigger to perform DDL on the same table which triggered the action

Tags: oracle, triggers

Is it possible to create a DDL trigger to perform DDL on the same table which fires the trigger.

```
`create or replace trigger ddl_trigger after DDL on schema when 
(ora_dict_obj_type = 'TABLE')
declare
cmd varchar2(4000);
begin
cmd := 'alter table '||ora_dict_obj_name ||' add (clob_col clob)';
execute immediate cmd;
end;
/
show errors`

`create table lob_tab(id number);`
```

when a table is created, am expecting that the triggered gets fired to add clob column to the table.

Comment: What happens when you test your script. Do you get any errors?

Comment: you want a ddl Trigger on ddl Action? it dioesn't make sense! Did you think about what happens after the DDL action? the trigger is executed again. it leads to an endless action

Comment: True, but it will face an error the second time since the column is already there in the table and it can't add  the same again. Nonetheless, it  is simply a senseless exercise to have a ddl trigger like this.